# python multiprocess hangs when calling a tensorflow model

Tags: multithreading, loops, multiprocessing

I am trying to train some models in parallel using a loop. However it hangs and does not proceeds with the .fit method.

```
def crossover_during_training(pair):

    print("FOR PAIR NUMBER " + str(pair))

    for index in [1, 5, 10, 15]:
        print("one")
        model = model_keras(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, 0)
        model_one = model_keras(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, pair)
        model_two = model_keras(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, pair+100)
    
        print(model, model_one, model_two)

        print(x_train.shape)
        model_information_parent_one = model_one.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=index, 
             batch_size=128, verbose=True, validation_data=(x_test, y_test)) 
        print(model_information_parent_one)
        weights_nn_one = model_one.get_weights()
        model_information_parent_two = model_two.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=index, 
             batch_size=128, verbose=True, validation_data=(x_test, y_test)) 
        weights_nn_two = model_two.get_weights()
    
        print("two")
```

This is how I simply use the multiprocessing module

```
all_args = [pair for pair in range(2)]
pool = Pool(2) 
results = pool.map(crossover_during_training, all_args)
```

The crossover_during_training function runs but never goes past the model.fit.. In other words it never reaches the print("two") bit.

Is there anything I am doing wrong in calling the fit method within a processor?

Comment: for future references, I found that using the Pool method from "multiprocessing.dummy" instead of "multiprocessing" works fine.

Comment: Did you find any reason for this? I am trying to run parallel prediction pipelines in a docker container, and my program keeps hanging when using multiprocessing, but works fine when using multiprocessing.dummy. When I run the program outside of docker both work fine...

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it already. The problem was that in Docker, multiprocessing runs with set_start_method("fork"), setting it to "spawn" solved it.

Comment: @thijsvdp thanks, that worked! But I almost overlooked it because you didn't post it as an answer - I hope you don't me doing it for the next person that comes here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem while running inside a docker container and the solution @thijsvdp pointed out in his comment worked for me:

```
multiprocessing.get_context('spawn').Pool(pool_size)
```